# Element pushing to next line in IE 10

Tags: css

This works in Firefox/Chrome, but in IE the red slide of this slider gets bumped to the next line outside of the viewport.

The green and red sides and the handle are all floated left. I've tried applying a 300px width to `.stSlide` thinking that maybe the width of the slide was forcing the red piece to be pushed to the next line but that didn't solve it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xqYBnz5BHLP844kXJXKs?p=preview

```
.ngSlideToggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 28px;
}
.ngSlideToggle * {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.ngSlideToggle > input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.ngSlideToggle > .stSlide {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.stSlide > .stOff,
.stSlide > .stOn,
.stSlide > .stHandle {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.stSlide > .stOff,
.stSlide > .stOn {
    padding: 4px 10px;

    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #808080;
}
.stSlide > .stHandle {
    padding: 2px 1px 2px 0;
    min-width: 25px;
    background: #fdfdfd; /* Old browsers */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fdfdfd 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fdfdfd 0%,#ebebeb 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdfdfd', endColorstr='#ebebeb',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
    color: #c6c6c6;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.stSlide > .stOn {
    background: #8ab056; /* Old browsers */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #8ab056 0%,#a2c46b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8ab056 0%,#a2c46b 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8ab056', endColorstr='#a2c46b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: 1px solid #88a75c;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.stSlide > .stOff {
    background: #d4786a; /* Old browsers */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d4786a 0%,#e39080 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d4786a 0%,#e39080 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4786a', endColorstr='#e39080',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: 1px solid #bd6e61;
    border-left: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you're messing around with this currently, but in IE10 it worked fine just a bit ago.  Then it stopped working in Chrome when I reloaded it here...

Comment: For me everything works fine in IE10.

Comment: While this fixes IE 10, it messes up both Firefox and Chrome.  The handle is now off by 1 or 2 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing CSS for `.stSlide > .stOff, .stSlide > .stOn, .stSlide > .stHandle` with this:

```
.stSlide > .stOff,
.stSlide > .stOn,
.stSlide > .stHandle {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

What I've done here, I changed `display` to `inline-block` and removed `float`.
It's hard to say if this will work since for me everything works fine from the begining.
But it might help.

**EDIT**:

You can also add this properties to `.stSlide`

```
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

to make sure the spans will stay in the same line.

Comment: Are you saying it works correctly for you in IE 10 without any modifications?  I'll test this first chance I get... thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to make sure the red span won't break into new line. Please, consider it.